# Do all docker images require a base image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Im new to docker and trying to understand the idea of a base image. To elaborate on my question, i would like to take the example of MySQL. I can see in the MySQL [Dockerfile](https://github.com/dockerfile/mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile) that it uses ubuntu as a base image. Is it necessary that it use a linux base image?

My understanding is that when we use a regular OS (eg Ubuntu), MySQL will use the linux system calls to perform read/writes to persistence storage. Thus, I would expect that MySQL in docker would do the same, expect the system calls that are made to the Ubuntu image that MySQL sits on will be translated by docker to system calls made by the host kernel OS. Is my understanding correct?

This would mean that the ubuntu image doesn't have a kernel, so the application sitting on top of the ubuntu image thinks that its running on ubuntu, except the system calls are made to the kernel host OS, is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker images do not strictly require a base image.

You can start your Dockerfile with the line FROM scratch. This instructs Docker to build an image with nothing as the first layer.

See: https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

This is what you do when you're going to be inserting all the binaries you want in your image yourself.

If you look at the Ubuntu image, you'll see that it starts FROM scratch:

https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/3d44d0b838eeb78c5baee976a4a529976b326878/bionic/Dockerfile

Docker containers are basically just namespaces and cgroups on the host OS that isolate a set of resources. There is no separate kernel, or system call translation. They are processes running directly on the host kernel, only in isolation.

To illustrate this, you can run `systemd-cgtop` on a host machine when you have some containers running. Your running containers will show up under the control group /docker/YOUR_CONTAINERS_ID, and you can see what resources each container is consuming, the same way you see the processes running in your control group when you run the regular `top` command.

The reason you can run pretty much any flavor of linux container on pretty much any flavor of linux that can run Docker is because the kernel is compatible across distributions. That's also why you have to install a linux vm to be able to run Docker in Windows and Mac.

For more details, see: https://superuser.com/questions/889472/docker-containers-have-their-own-kernel-or-not

Answer (score 1):

In this context, a Linux distribution is just a bunch of files and there's not a hard requirement to have "a distribution" in a Docker image.

Let's take a simple, classic C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int args, char **argv) {
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

On a typical Linux system, `gcc` will produce an ELF binary file that says it needs a library `libc.so.6` in order to run.  When the program calls `printf()`, the implementation of that is in that library; and when that library code eventually makes a syscall to write to file descriptor 1, it will get forwarded to the kernel.

In Docker, all containers share the host's kernel, but have independent isolated filesystems.  So just so long as the image contains the binary and all of the shared libraries it depends on, it doesn't usually need a Linux distribution *per se*.  (The kernel is not part of the image, and if you're running an Ubuntu Docker image there isn't an "Ubuntu kernel"; it uses whatever the host is using.)

If that makes sense to you, and you're using a language that compiles to native binaries (C, C++, Go, Rust), then you can usually produce a static binary and build a Docker image `FROM scratch` containing *only* that binary (no "distribution", no libraries, no shell; be careful to not use the Docker `CMD string` form, because that will run `/bin/sh -c 'string'`, and you don't have a `/bin/sh`).  Or if you're confident in what you're doing you can build an image `FROM scratch` containing the `/lib/ld-linux.so` loader and the shared libraries you need, but not a distribution *per se*.

```sh
# Build the program, which needs a full C toolchain.
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential
WORKDIR /app
COPY hello.c .
RUN gcc -static -o hello hello.c

# Then create an image that _only_ contains the static binary.
FROM scratch
COPY --from=builder /app/hello /hello
ENTRYPOINT ["/hello"]
```